# AngularJS reference variables based on another variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to be able to reference a variable in an Angular template that is built up on another variable with a filter.

So for example, I might have this in the controller:

$scope.EuropaLeague = true;

If I do this in the template it works as expected:

```html
<div ng-if="EuropaLeague">

</div>
```

But what if I wanted to dynamically populate the ng-if with something coming from an ng-repeat e.g.

```html
{{item.leagueName | myFilter}}
```

So the above would reference my scope variable $scope.EuropaLeague E.g. True or False?

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that ng-if"{{item.leagueName | myFilter}}" doesn't work. It can only outputs the string 'EuropaLeague'. I want to reference the EuropaLeague scope variable.

Comment: can you provide a plunkar

Comment: Here is a Plunkar: https://plnkr.co/edit/HNEyDcbfCjIVo5CkqAa9 It should only show items that match 'ChampionsLeague'

Comment: I basically want to have check boxes that will filter out items in the ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working code:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.leagues =
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ChampionsLeague",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "EuropaLeague",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "FACup",
    }
  ]
  $scope.obj = {};
  $scope.obj['EuropaLeague'] = false;
  $scope.obj['FACup'] = false;
  $scope.obj['ChampionsLeague'] = true;
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in leagues" ng-if="item.name">
      <li ng-if="obj[item.name]">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks.

Comment: @NeilSingh glad to help :-)